# .net windows application with sql database + create a setup

Tags: .net, windows, set

I have created one windows application in .net 2.0 and it uses SQL database in back end.

I want to create a setup file for this application so that I can install it and run it on any machine which does not have either .NET framework or SQL Server.

Please give me some useful link for this.

Comment: I would first ask does it possible or not and just not try to find a link. Do you expect your setup to install .NET on users machine. And even so how you imagine your application to work without SQL DB. By the way do you mean MS SQL. If so which addition. In other words more details.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.google.com/search?q=visual+studio+web+setup+project+tutorial

The SQL Server part is going to be the tricky part.  You're not going to be able to package SQL Server with your project.  Maybe SQL Lite?  I haven't used it, but adjust the above search accordingly and see what you can find.